# Nano keyboard shortcut to go through line faster?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, nano

Is there an shortcut in nano for moving through a line faster? I have some log files with gigantic lines and getting to the middle of them is awful.

I know I could use a different text editor that doesn't have this particular problem (less will wrap lines), but I'm used to nano and I like a lot of its other features.

Comment: You can also `Esc + m`, to enable mouse support. Then just click on the position where you want the cursor.

Answer (score 46):

Here are the shortcuts for moving through a line in nano.

Use these to go faster through a line:

`ctrl + space` move one word **forward** in a line.

`alt + space` move one word **backwards** in a line.

Other line shortcuts:

`ctrl + f` move one character **forward** in a line.

`ctrl + b` move one character **backwards** in a line.

`ctrl + a` move to the **beginning** of a line.

`ctrl + e` move to the **end** of a line

To move to a specific line use `ctrl + _`.
You may want to check out more [Nano Keyboard Commands](http://staffwww.fullcoll.edu/sedwards/Nano/NanoKeyboardCommands.html)

Comment: For the record, Alt-Space doesn't seem to to work in OS X, the key combo is Esc-Space. But Ctrl-Space works fine, and is a great shortcut. I've been using Nano (and Pico before that) for 20 years and didn't know about it!

Comment: Unfortunately Esc-Space doesn't work for me on OSX.  I had to do the following: Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Keyboard > "Use option as meta key".

Comment: Both ctrl + space (move one word forward in a line) and alt + space (move one word backwards in a line) shortcuts don't seem to work in my macOS High Sierra.